# Wireless firmware missing!

Tags: wireless, firmware

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on the Win 7 machine for the first time. I'm unaware of any commands.

I'm unable to connect the Internet using my laptop. I haven't tried using the wired connection.

It gives the error that 'Wireless firmware missing'.

What should I do ?

Comment: its worth rebooting, connecting via a wired connection, make sure you have working internet and then open the "additional drivers" window.  You may have a wireless driver to activate.  If you dont, please have a look at this Q&A and post some details by editing your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what make of a wireless card you have? I have this issue after every update, but this is a known issue with broadcom cards. If you have that card try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Installing%20STA%20drivers it works for me, unlike the Restricted Driver option